# Disable all the tooltips on a GNOME/RHEL7 Desktop!

Tags: rhel, gnome, desktop-environment

How can I disable all the tooltips in RHEL7 using GNOME gui?

Tooltips are full of bugs: it shows it at a window, and it stays at the top in another window!

Comment: Are you using the default OOTB theme or have you installed/configured another theme?

Answer (score 1):

This is defined in the settings-ini from the themes.

For Example

```
cat /usr/share/themes/Albatross/gtk-3.0/settings.ini 
[Settings]
gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nbg_color:#ededed\ntooltip_bg_color:#d6dce4\nselected_bg_color:#a9b7c4\ntext_color:#444444\nfg_color:#202020\ntooltip_fg_color:#222222\nselected_fg_color:#333333"
gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
gtk-visible-focus = automatic
```

Swap automatic to false.

Edit: Right file, but wrong key `gtk-enable-tooltips = false`

Comment: This has been deprecated [as of `gtk+` 3.10](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-enable-tooltips)